# Setting up a git remote origin

Tags: git

I have the following repos.

1. DEV REPO: in a directory on my development machine where i make changes
2. MAIN REPO: bare repository on my development machine to which i push changes from dev repo
3. PRODUCTION REPO: repository on host machine to pull updates from the main repo

I used `git remote add origin /Users/me/sites/main_repo` to set the MAIN repo as origin for the DEV repo. The PRODUCTION repo is on a remote host. Can i use a variation of the same command to set the MAIN repo as origin for the PRODUCTION repo also? If "yes", then i suppose the syntax would include an ip address. What would that look like?

Comment: Didn't you mean "to set the PRODUCTION repo as origin for the MAIN repo"?

Answer (score 331, accepted):

Using SSH

```
git remote add origin ssh://login@IP/path/to/repository
```

Using HTTP

```
git remote add origin http://IP/path/to/repository
```

However having a simple `git pull` as a deployment process is usually a **bad idea** and should be avoided in favor of a real deployment script.

Comment: Why is it a really bad idea? Doing some searches now for deployment script examples.

Comment: Because deploying often mean (read "always") more than just what `git pull` do. You might need to setup the production DB credentials, clear the cache, increase the version number, backup the older version so you can roll back if things go wrong, optimized/minify your assets (CSS and Js for example) and a bazillions of other things.

Comment: @ClementHerreman - it seems like, based on your explanation, using git pull is not so much a "bad idea" as it is a limited solution.  Sometimes I find git pull to be a perfectly effective, simple deployment solution when I have a simple scenario.

Comment: @Brady that's why I wrote "often" instead of always. There's no 100% always true rule.

Comment: I think you need to specify ssh:// for the ssh way, i.e., git remote add origin ssh://login@IP/path/to/repository

Comment: @kakyo is it really needed?

Comment: I think if we modified the final statement to "is sometimes a bad idea" no bold this would be an excellent answer.

Comment: The bad idea comes in, when you start having credentials embedded in git as well. The 2nd reason it could be bad, is if you use public repos', that is a possible vector of attack, by cracking your credentials there, and push a malicious commit

Comment: It's also a bad idea because it's not expected. If I saw a git repo on a deployment server, I would assume it was because there wasn't a separate machine for source files.

Comment: Note that `path/to/repository` needs to be absolute path. or `~/path/...`.

Answer (score 144):

For anyone who comes here, as I did, looking for the syntax to **change** origin to a different location you can find that documentation here: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/. Using `git remote add` to do this will result in "fatal: remote origin already exists."

Nutshell:
`git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/repo`

(The marked answer is correct, I'm just hoping to help anyone as lost as I was... haha)

Comment: This answer is better for people wanting to change "git remote url" if it already exists. Thanks @lostphilosopher

Answer (score 19):

You can include the branch to track when setting up remotes, to keep things working as you might expect:

```
git remote add --track master origin user@somesite.com:group/project.git   # git
git remote add --track master origin user@172.16.1.100:group/project.git   # git w/IP
git remote add --track master origin http://github.com/group/project.git   # http
git remote add --track master origin http://172.16.1.100/group/project.git # http w/IP
git remote add --track master origin /Volumes/Git/group/project/           # local
git remote add --track master origin G:/group/project/                     # local, Win
```

This keeps you from having to manually edit your git config or specify branch tracking manually.