# Intellij IDEA how to upload project to remote branch with git plugin?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have Intellij IDEA 12.0.1
I am using build-in Git plugin. I am able to create local repository. Now I want to upload my source code to remote repository. Can I do this with Intellij IDEA plugin?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are able to do it on the command line with `git push` then you should be able to do it with IntelliJ. From the context menu: `Git -> Repository -> Push`

Comment: It gives me error, as I don't have remote branch

Comment: You should add the remote origin from the command line: `git remote add origin http://IP/path/to/repository`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259535/git-setting-up-a-remote-origin

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can't upload your local Git repository to remote using IntelliJ IDEA plugin. For this you need to use [Git Bash](http://git-scm.com/downloads) or Git client, for example [Source Tree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/).

### To create local Git repository with IntelliJ IDEA plugin

1. In IntelliJ IDEA menu `VCS -> Import into Version Control -> Create Git Repository`
2. In pop up window select your project and click ok.
3. Commit all necessary files to you local branch `master`

### To upload local repository to remote using Git Bash

1. Open **Git Bash** and navigate to your project folder e.g cd `'D:\projects\TestProject'`
2. In **Git Bash** `git remote add origin http//IP/path/to/repository`
3. In **Git Bash** `git push origin master`
4. In **IntelliJ IDEA** right-click on project select `Synchronize 'TestProject'`
5. In **IntelliJ IDEA** right-click on project select `Git -> Repository -> Branches -> origin/master -> Checkout as new local branch`

### To upload local repository to remote using Source Tree

1. In **Source Tree** `File -> Open` and navigate to your project folder e.g cd `'D:\projects\TestProject'`
2. In **Source Tree** `Repository -> Add Remote`, you should see **Repository Settings** window
   [image]
3. Click **Add** button, and fill **Remote details**
   [image]
4. Finally click **Ok** button
   Now you should be able to do pull/push using IntelliJ IDEA plugin.
5. In **IntelliJ IDEA** right-click on project select `Synchronize 'TestProject'`
6. In **IntelliJ IDEA** right-click on project select `Git -> Repository -> Branches -> origin/master -> Checkout as new local branch`

---

Now you should be able to do **pull/push** using **IntelliJ IDEA** plugin.

Comment: I came here because I was pretty sure I was missing how/where to do remote management through the ui. Guess it doesn't exist. Strange..

Comment: @Rob you can vote on this feature [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87099)

Comment: Thanks for the post. If in the PhpStorm documentation it would just say that it does not directly support this operation and that you must use Git Bash, it would make google searching much easier.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible in Intellij IDEA.
You should add a remote repository for your local repository in git bash by below command.

```
git remote add origin YOUR_REMOTE_REPOSITORY_ADDRESS.
for example
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/my_account/my_repository.git
```

In Intellij IDEA when you want to commit any change to repository use `ctrl + k` and it will show you a window like below image. In this window you can choose `commit and push` so it will commits and push change to local and remote repository.
[image]
Also if you want to only push to remote repository use `ctrl + shift + k` to pushing changes.
I hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I believe this is still the case with IDEA 12 unless I'm mistaken:

An alternative to using the command line would be SourceTree (available for Mac & Win) to manage remotes or manage Git/Hg repositories completely. It is a free GUI client from Atlassian (no affiliation disclosure).

You can download it [here](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/).

Comment: You are right, I am using it too, please put download link in your  answer.