# git push error while pushing to remote repository

Tags: git, heroku

I am getting the following error while trying to push the changes to remote repository.

**Command**

`git push heroku`

**Error**

`fatal: You are pushing to remote 'heroku', which is not the upstream of
your current branch 'master', without telling me what to push
to update which remote branch.`

Can anyone please advise what might be causing the same?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I suspect you don't have remote configured.

push likes to know WHAT to push and WHERE to push it. Usually one configures git so that it automatically tracks branches (local - remote pairs).

Try pushing: `git push heroku master` assuming master is your local branch and heroku is a remote.

Also, to see if remote is not configured, (l)ist your config or (e)dit it:
`git config -l / -e`

Since Felix was before me, I'll extend my answer with setting the remote:

- [nice SO question in the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259535/git-setting-up-a-remote-origin)
- [Git Guys explain remote section of config](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/the-configuration-file-remote-section/)

Comment: Mate do you mean the following config ? `branch.master.remote=origin`

Comment: @Misguided - the line you quote tells you branch master has remote mapped to "origin". Quite possibly you will see also `remote.origin.url=...` - this tells you where to look your remote and most likely has "heroku" in. 

I've just added the link that explains it in more detail. Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 7):

**git config -l** will show you:

[branch.master.remote] and [branch.master.merge]

Actually, they are the default behaviors of git pull/push, for example, **git push** == **git push [branch.master.remote] [branch.master.merge]**.

By default, [branch.master.remote] = origin, [branch.master.merge] = master, so in this situation **git push** = **git push origin master**.

However, in your situation, your origin [branch.master.remote] is not **heroku**, and git does not know which branch of **heroku*** you wanna push to, so you must point it for git.

Comment: below are my said configurations `branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master`

Comment: @misguided   Right, if you can use this command: **git branch --upstream heroku/master** to change branch.master.remote and branch.master.merge, then you can use **git push heroku** or **git push** instead of **git push heroku master**.

Comment: I get the following error `git branch --upstream heroku
error: unknown option `upstream'`

Comment: @misguided Try **git branch master --set-upstream heroku/master**

Answer (score -4):

It could be more simple than that, try to run heroku login, if heroku is not reconigzed as a command you simple don't have the heroku toolbelt installed if that is the case follow the instructions on that site https://toolbelt.heroku.com/debian for your OS

Comment: Not at all what the OP is asking, all they needs to do is add the `heroku` remote to his git repo. This does not require the toolbelt.