# Push from one repo to another - Git

Tags: git, push, remote-server, pull

I have a repo on my local computer. I want to develop and make changes in a branch on my local repo and then push these changes for testing to a repo on a server that I can ssh into. How do I do this? I have never pushed/pulled from the local to the server, only pulled down through SSH from my bitbucket account to either my local computer or remote server.

Thanks,
Mo

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259535/git-setting-up-a-remote-origin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a repo on the server by logging in to it, and do a `git init --bare`.

Then on you local computer you

```
git remote add serverrepo <url to server repo>
```

Now you can push and pull to the serverrepo, and to origin (bitbucket?).

You can push your branch to just the serverrepo if you wish:

```
git push -u serverrepo branchname
```

If you need to "publish" the repo on the server somehow, you can follow [this guide](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto).

Comment: after following the tutorial, making a bare repo, I try to add the remote repo and get "fatal: not a git repository". this is the command I am using `git remote add web ssh://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/home/mo/dev.git`

Comment: Have you changed directory to your git repo on the local machine?

Comment: I didn't... that was the problem. But now the post-receive doesn't seem to work correctly. I'll keep at it and try to work it out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the command line and are using Atlassian SourceTree do Repository->Add Remote on the source repository and then you can push your changes to the destination.