# Is there any way I can download my repository as a zip and add to my local repository instead of using git (repo snc command)?

Tags: git, github, synchronization

Is there any way I can download my repository first and then copy the contents to my local repository. I will need to sync with it later.

> Edit: This is not possible at all. The download zip at
>   Github/Bitbucket just give the current snapshot of the repository
>   without any history. This will make it impossible to
>   contribute/synchronize with repository updates. If bandwidth is the
>   issue, people should do a "shallow-clone" which allows you to get a
>   repository with very less history and you can still contribute back to
>   it.

Comment: It would be better to provide an answer with the new information, instead of making the question obsolete itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can do that if you use GitHub, Bitbucket etc.

There is a download Zip button.

Make sure you setup the remote after that so that you can push your new changes and pull new changes[image]

To setup the remote you can check this post:
[Setting up a git remote origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259535/setting-up-a-remote-origin)

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer , I download zip and extract to my repository then? @geo-paul

Comment: I'm sorry but I still cannot do it. @Geo Paul

Answer (score 0):

perhaps create a bash which :

1. git clone repo
2. mv, cp or rm anything anywhere
3. last process between your repo and the repo you are git cloned

Downloaded Zip repo it's just a git clone in a zip...

Comment: Can you elaborate more, I'm new to this